# Generic getter in container object

Tags: java, oop

Some container class holds list of objects of base class "Table" (like WoodenTable, MetalTable...). Each Table class keeps its MaterialType (MaterialType.Wood, MaterialType.Metal...). Question is how to provide proper getter method for container class that could return each SubClass of Table.

So far I've found following ways:

1.Getter with material type as parameter. Danger here is ClassCastException if type of T doesn't correspond to materialType:

```
<T extends Table> T getTable(MaterialType materialtype)
WoodenTable table = getTable(MaterialType.Wood);
MetalTable table = getTable(MaterialType.Wood); // ups... exception
```

2.Getter with Class parameter. Safe but not so clear for user (comparing to MaterialType as parameter):

```
<T extends Table> T getTable(Class<T> tableClass)
WoodenTable table = getTable(WoodenTable.class);
```

3.Getter for each Table SubClass. Cumbersome to use,write and add new Table subClasses:

```
WoodenTable getWoodenTable()
WoodenTable table = getWoodenTable();
```

4.Getter for just Table interface. Cast done outside of container class if necessary.

```
Table getTable(MaterialType materialType)
WoodenTable woodenTable = (WoodenTable)getTable(MaterialType.Wood)
```

Is any other (better) way to do that? If not, then which of those would be most appriopriate or least smelly?

Comment: Don't mix typing by enum with typing by subclass. Pick one, and stick with it.

Comment: How can I avoid it? Considering Woot4Moo reponse below I need something like the option 4. The only way I could avoid enums completely is by going with option 3 (not very appealing).

Comment: Is the container colleciton homogenous (contains always the same base type) or heterogenous (contains different base type)?

Comment: I would look at the Typesafe Heterogeneous Container pattern, and see how to extend it for lists of objects, instead of a singel object. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1959547/217862

Comment: @ewernli Yeah, thats quite similar to the option 2 I've used so far. Thanks, good to know that this thing has a name!

Answer (score 0):

It should be just this simple:

```
public Table getTable()  
{  
     return this.table;
}
```

This will return a `Table` object it is up to the invoker to do with it what they want.  Similar to the following block:

```
public Collection<String> getCollection()  
{  
     return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

The body returns an `ArrayList` but the function really returns a `Collection`.  A well defined API that utilizes the most common interface between objects will give you this same flexibility.

**EDIT**

> Yes, that could be one use case but quite often I need also something
>   like : for(Table t : TableContainer) {
>   (SubClassA)t.doSomethingSpecificForA();} and that's were my problems
>   begin.

Let us assume the following interface and implementations:

```
    public interface Table  
    {  
        Table getTable();  
        void doSpecial();  
    }


public class WoddenTable implements Table  
{  
     ...  
     public Table getTable()  
     {  
         return this;
     }    

     public void doSpecial()  
     {  
         mySpecial();  
     }  

     private void mySpecial()  
     {  
         System.out.println("Wooden");  
     }  
}    

public class MetalTable implements Table  
{  
     ...  
     public Table getTable()  
     {  
         return this;
     }    

     public void doSpecial()  
     {  
         mySpecial();  
     }  

     private void mySpecial()  
     {  
         System.out.println("Metal");  
     } 
}
```

and the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  
{  
        Collection<Table> tables = new ArrayList<Table>();  
        tables.add(new WoodenTable());  
        tables.add(new MetalTable());  
        for(Table table : tables)  
        {  
              table.doSpecial();  
        }  
}
```

The approach here is that there is a shared public API.  And the internals of each class are not exposed so the need to do something `special` for each class is hidden behind the common interface.  This prevents having to do instance of checks or any of the other messy ways to solve this type of problem.

Comment: My problem here is that I often have to work on functions unique for SubClasses not provided by the interface. This means a need to somehow specify which Subclass i want to get from the container class (to avoid "instanceof").

Comment: @CzujnyJakZuraw Right I understand the problem.  In the Collection example above it would be resolved like this:  `Set<String> strings = new HashSet<String>(getCollection());`  .  In your use case you would do it the same way like so:  `TableSubA a = new TableSubA(getTable());`

Comment: Either you are missing my point or it's me who doesn't understand something here :). Maybe I should emphasize that my TableContainer object holds many different kinds of tables. How would you, in this case, retrieve all wooden tables from it without specifying any type parameter?

Comment: @CzujnyJakZuraw Sure your TableContainer holds many different table types.  And to confirm you want to do something like this:  `for(Table t : TableContainer)  { t.doSomething();}`   correct?  Or is there some case I am missing?

Comment: Yes, that could be one use case but quite often I need also something like : for(Table t : TableContainer) { (SubClassA)t.doSomethingSpecificForA();} and that's were my problems begin.

Comment: @CzujnyJakZuraw the most obvious way, to me, to solve this problem is to use an overridden function.  Specifically some general method that all Tables must implement.  Within each class you can delegate to a private method but the public interface should have zero issue with this type of problem.  Please see my edit

Comment: All right, it seems i'll have to put some effort and move SubClasses functions into the interface. Thanks for help!

Comment: @CzujnyJakZuraw no don't do that!  You just want a common function that has a unique implementation based on private / helper methods inside each of the subclasses.  Interfaces should **only** contain **common** functions

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to stop thinking about tables as about data structures with attributes (material), and start treating them as "persons" ([Object Thinking](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619654)). Don't get a "material" out of them. Instead, let them expose their behavior.

When you change the design of the table you will automatically change the design of their container. And it will become obvious that the container shouldn't care about tables' materials, but should let **them** control whether they want to get out of container or remain there.