# Building custom Java objects with different components (capabilities)

Tags: java, oop

Consider that I have multiple objects that has different functionality. Lets assume that these objects do not really have much in common.

I want to have an another object which is a composition of these objects. I was wondering what would be best way to do this. For example, if we were to call these objects A, B, and C, I want to have a container object that contains these A, B, and C. The key is, the container can be constructed with only what it needs, e.g. if it only needs A, it will only have A. If it needs only A and C, it will contain only A and C. I was wondering what the most effective way to do this would be? I could always tie these A,B, and C behind some marker interface, but I feel like these A, B, and C might not be very related (very different set of functionalities). Also, it will require some casting to get the desired object if tied behind an arbitrary interface.

Any suggestions on what I am trying to solve? I'd imagine some of the GUI frameworks might achieve what I am trying to, e.g. having containers that have different capabilities based on callers needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They must have something in common at all, if there is any reason you want them in a composition. I think the most Java-like approach would be a common superclass for all of them, and then an implementation of some `Collection` of those objects as a field in another class.

Comment: The reason why I don't like superclasses here is when I see the need of inheritance, I usually feel that all implmentation classes should have exactly the same method signatures. What I am confused about is though in my case, even if I were to have some super class, A will have APIs that B won't have, etc. Maybe I am not approaching from the right angle...

Comment: Each of these classes, A, B, etc. are capabilities that a container object will have. Maybe I am thinking too hard. :)

Comment: Hmm, I might be using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959523/how-to-find-object-of-given-type-in-a-heterogeneous-list/1959547#1959547 with your suggestion as a solution.

Comment: But they don't need to have ALL methods from the superclass, only abstract methods must be inherited, plus if they only implement them as method stubs, without body, it is not against any OOP principles that I know of ;)